# How to suppress a Mariadb variable required for variable row calculation but not for Insert

Tags: sql, variables, mariadb, insert-into

I have a SQL Insert statement that uses a Select to populate a table.

All was well until I had to concat the sitename with postcode for processing purposes.

The SQL needs to return a `row_id` for each sitename/postcode combination but I don't want to insert this combination into the table and don't really want to create a new column in the insert table - only the sitename.

I can't see how to achieve this -  code snippet follows.

```
SET @row_number  = 0; 
INSERT INTO mis.temp_site_extraction_line_costing
(row_id, `Site Company Name`,.........)
select 
@row_number :=
CASE 
    WHEN @site_name=concat(m1.`Site Company Name`,m1.sitepostcode) then @row_number+1
    ELSE 1
END as rowid,
@site_name :=concat(m1.`Site Company Name`, m1.`sitepostcode`),
m1.`Site Company Name` as site_company_name,
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move your `SELECT` into a subquery.  That is, instead of

```
SELECT @row_number := ..., other_stuff
```

do

```
SELECT other_stuff
    FROM (
        SELECT @row_number := ..., other_stuff
         ) AS x
```